# UltraGrid Validation Issues

Tags: vb.net, validation, date, decimal, infragistics

I've got a few issues that have been raised with the end user of my application in terms of validation of the grids I've got.

One of the issues is that 2 of the columns are Date columns, so the cells contain `DatePickers` to allow entry of data. However, the user is unable to select the current date in these cells, for whatever reason. 
If they select a previous/future date first then they can change it to the current date, but this isn't the most efficient thing to do, of course.

Is there any reason why the grid isn't allowing selection of the current date without selecting a different date first?

Secondly, the decimal columns aren't validating correctly. I'm setting the `MaskInput` property of certain columns in the `InitializeLayout` method, using the following code

```
e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns("currentRate").MaskInput = "{double:9.2}"
e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns("newRate").MaskInput = "{double:9.2}"
```

Yet, when clicking on either of these columns, the cell will show the string {double:9.2} (Which can't be deleted), then when clicking off the cell without entering a value will just show an empty cell. The cell also only allows a single digit and a decimal place, rather than 2 DP's.

What is wrong with the code I'm using?

The third and final issue isn't the most vital things ever, but when clicking on cells, the text in the cell isn't automatically highlighted, so the user has to delete each character to clear the cell.

How can I make it select the text in a cell automatically when clicking on the cell?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix easily your last issue. To do so, get the editor of the cell, where the user has clicked, and call over the editor SelectAll method like this:

```
private void UltraGrid_AfterEnterEditMode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as UltraGrid;
    if(grid == null)
        return;

    var activeCell = grid.ActiveCell;
    if(activeCell == null)
        return;

    var editor = activeCell.EditorResolved;
    if(editor == null)
        return;

    editor.SelectAll();
}
```

Regarding your first two issues, IMHO this is not the default behavior of the grid. The grid will not stop you to select any day from calendar drop down if you did not tell it to do so, as well as it will display the number according to provided mask. So I can suggest you to check your code to see if you are not handling any events forcing the grid to behave in this way.

Comment: I actually used a different method to select the text in the grid, but thanks for your idea (I'm using vb, not C#, however). Do you have any ideas what might be causing the other issues? What sort of code might be overriding it?

Answer (score 0):

The way that I solved the issue with text selection was to do the following:

```
Private Sub ugProducts_AfterEnterEditMode(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ugProducts.AfterEnterEditMode

    Dim activeCell As UltraGridCell = ugProducts.ActiveCell
    Dim editor = activeCell.EditorResolved
    If editor IsNot Nothing Then
        If TypeOf editor Is CheckEditor AndAlso TypeOf editor Is EditorWithCombo Then
        Else
            editor.SelectionStart = 0
            editor.SelectionLength = activeCell.Text.Length
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

For some reason, it wouldn't allow the use of `IsNot`, so I had to settle for `Is` with an `Else` statement. But this would do the trick, or for `C#` users, use @wnvko's suggestion.